# Why does a Email Server test timeout?

Tags: email, dns

When I go to https://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx, enter my domain (pairofdocs.net), and click ‘Test email server’, I get the error message:

```
Connecting to 23.23.216.253
2/19/2021 9:23:30 AM Connection attempt #1 - Unable to connect after 15 seconds.
```

I have no idea why this is happening – any suggestions?

I have used the test previously and it worked. My domain is configured as follows:

- DNS – on NameCheap.com
- Web site (a simple one) – on Amazon Web Services
- Email – handled by Zoho

I rebuilt my domain about six months ago, on a new AWS instance - whose IP address is 23.23.216.253, and do not recall the problem’s having happened prior to the rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Email hosting is outsource to Zoho, there is a pretty good chance the email server has been setup correctly and has a pretty decent uptime.

It is likely the problem you are having is with how you are connecting to the email server although the error you've provided shows what seems to be an offline email server.